# State machine based testing in Haskell QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, erlang, quickcheck

Does Haskell QuickCheck have the state machine based features that John Hughes' describes in the following talk and paper -

- http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/232550/local_232550.pdf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi0rHwfiX1Q

If not, how does one actually do stateful testing using Haskell's QuickCheck? For example, what is the best way to test a circular buffer using Haskell QuickCheck without reimplementing the core logic in the test itself.

Comment: A QuickCheck property about a stateful or nonstateful function is the same thing - it's just another function whose return type is `Property`. You are probably looking for [`Test.QuickCheck.Monadic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Monadic.html)

Comment: Actually I'm lookin for a real-life example of using Haskell QC to check a real-life stateful system without duplicating core logic in the test itself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any explicit support in QuickCheck, but I think the general approach in Haskell would be something like the following example.

It tests a test system (custom `List` instance) against a model (a real Haskell list).  The key is to generate arbitrary sequences of stateful primitive operations (e.g., `Push`, `Pop`, and `IsEmpty`) and apply them to both the test system and the model in a monadic fashion, checking post conditions after each operation.  In this case, the post conditions are just to test that operations that return values (`pop` and `isEmpty`) return the same values for the test system and model, but it could easily be modified to test other post conditions (or add pre-conditions).

If a test fails, it will return a minimal sequence of operations applied to the empty list that causes the post conditions to fail.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}

module ListTest where

import Test.QuickCheck
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad

-- |The system to test

data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving (Show, Eq)
push x lst = Cons x lst
pop (Cons x lst) = (Just x, lst)
pop Empty = (Nothing, Empty)
isEmpty Empty = True
isEmpty _     = False

-- |The model (based on plain Haskell lists)

type Model a = [a]
pushM = (:)
popM []     = (Nothing, [])
popM (x:xs) = (Just x, xs)
isEmptyM [] = True
isEmptyM _  = False

-- |Operations on lists of `a`s
data Op a = Push a | Pop | IsEmpty deriving (Show, Eq)
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Op a) where
  arbitrary = oneof ([Push <$> arbitrary, pure Pop, pure IsEmpty])

-- |For each op, return tuple of: (return values matched?, (new List, new Model))
compare_op :: (Eq a) => Op a -> (List a, Model a) -> (All, (List a, Model a))
compare_op (Push x) (lst, mdl) = -- True b/c no return value to compare
                                 (All True, (push x lst, pushM x mdl))
compare_op Pop      (lst, mdl) = let (y1, lst') = pop lst
                                     (y2, mdl') = popM mdl
                                 in  (All (y1 == y2), (lst', mdl'))
compare_op IsEmpty  (lst, mdl) = (All (isEmpty lst == isEmptyM mdl), (lst, mdl))

-- |The property that a sequence of operations has matching return values.
prop_model :: [Op Int] -> Bool
prop_model ops = (getAll . fst . foldM (flip compare_op) (Empty, [])) ops

main :: IO ()
main = quickCheck prop_model
```

Comment: Isn't there any support for pre/post conditions in QC? This code looks very different from what's on John Hughes' slides! Also, is it always possible to have a simplified model of business applications without duplicating the core logic itself?

Comment: A lot of the time the logic in a real world application is obscured by various things. For example, someone may have taken straightforward logic and spread it around in a class hierarchy or deeply nested calls, or you could be dealing with a microservices architecture. It may not always be possible to make a simplified model, but software has a tendency to grow in complexity over time, so it's likely enough to be worth a try.